# scala: instance variables and object initialization

Tags: scala

I've been thinking of scala objects as simply shorthand for singleton java objects - that is, I'd expect them to behave like objects with guaranteed singleton instantiation. Then I run into something like this, which I don't understand:

```
object Test  extends App{
 var x ="a"

 override def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
   println(x )
 }
}
```

which prints **null** rather than "a".

Looking at the generated classes, I get a Test$.class which is the object definition; however the instance value "a" is defined in a companion Test class using a generated delayedInit. Can someone shed some light on how this is instantiated? Clearly the mental model I had of this is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first take a look at `App` and how it works. The [documentation of App](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App) reveals the following caveats:

> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the
>   [DelayedInit](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.DelayedInit) functionality, which means that fields of the object will
>   not have been initialized before the main method has been executed.
>
> It should also be noted that the main method will not normally need to
>   be overridden: the purpose is to turn the whole class body into the
>   “main method”. You should only chose to override it if you know what
>   you are doing.

### Your example

Ok, great. Now that we know these two facts, let's fix your code. There are two possible solutions we can consider:

Let's only override the main method when we know what we're doing:

```
object Test extends App{
 var x ="a"
 println(x )
}
```

Or we can choose to define a `main` method, but not extend `App`:

```
object Test {
 var x ="a"

 def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
   println(x )
 }
}
```

### Conclusion

You're understanding of objects is correct. What's confusing is the [DelayedInit](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.DelayedInit) that `App` implements. Happy coding ;)